# How can Java remove leading whitespace?

Tags: java, string, removing-whitespace

I have been trying to figure out why this Java code won't delete any leading whitespace to my actual string, I have been trying to use stripLeading() method and the trim(); method, and various other methods with the same functionality but still haven't gotten a favorable outcome. Code:

```
public static String message(String logLine) {
         logLine = (String) logLine.subSequence(logLine.indexOf(" ") + 1, logLine.length());
         return logLine;
         }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println(message("[WARNING]:   \tTimezone not set  \r\n"));
    }
```

What results is what I wanted, just the words "Timezone not set" however I want this program to completely ignore leading whitespace, which for some reason it can't. Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's not a leading whitespace if there's text before it.

Comment: Try `.indexOf(" ")` on a few strings, maybe `"    x"`, `"x y"`, `"x "` and think about the results.

Comment: maybe `string.substring(string.indexOf(" ")).trim()` (or  `... .stripLeading()` [Java 11+])

Comment: `logLine = logLine.split("\\s+",2)[1].trim();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions

- Use `String::replaceFirst` to keep only the part after a prefix (`[WARNING]:`) followed by whitespaces and the main part:

  ```java
  public static String message(String logLine) {
      return logLine.replaceFirst("^\\S*\\s+(\\S+(\\s+\\S+)*)\\s+$", "$1");
  }
  ```
- As the prefix ends with `':'`, a solution offered in the comment using `String::substring` + `String::trim` works too:

  ```java
  public static String message(String logLine) {
      return logLine.substring(logLine.indexOf(":") + 1).trim();
  }
  ```